# How to know if a push notification has been read or at least delivered in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, push

I added a push notification in my JB and my requirement is to send an SMS after some hours if the subscriber did not open or see the push notification.
Is there a way to get this information any how?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a listener to be notified.

See [**NotificationManager.NotificationMessageDisplayedListener**](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/6.4/reference/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/notifications/NotificationManager.NotificationMessageDisplayedListener.html)

In your application, you could set a `tag` (ref. [Device/Contact Registration](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html)) based on the message being received or opened.  That `tag` would be sent up with the device registration and become visible in `MobilePush Demographics`.  It could then be used to create inclusion/exclusion lists to target people with messages via automations.

Comment: thank you Adam. This should be added in the android app, right? How can I pass this info from the android listener to Marketing cloud? What is supposed to be set up? thank you again

Comment: Adam?  It's my answer.  Adam just make the link prettier ;)  And, yes, the method is part of the Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK ... it should be added to your application.

Comment: after adding the displayedlistener and the contact see the push message, what marketing cloud field is supposed to change? thank u!

Comment: Thank u Bill, apologies I got confused, do u know what marketing cloud field is supposed to change?

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you could determine on the server-side if the message has been shown or clicked on the device.

Comment: thank u Bill, I'll test it and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no Data View available out of the box for Push Tracking. One thought  of what you can do is to automate/schedule the [Push Message Detail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_push_message_detailed_report.htm&type=5) report to an FTP. And then import this to a Data Extension which you add to an Attribute Group. Then you can refer to this in your Journey.

Haven't tried it out myself. But should be possible.